# select object based of value with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, json.net

I'm quite new into Json, but came a long way with help of other questions, but now I'm stuck.

I have a Json file that looks something like this:

```
{
"Entries": [{
        "Id": "7fefda06f24e4611ae64aba700943e2b",
        "RowId": 30,
        "FormId": "5d4a8143084b4c16a920ab0a00c905e5",
        "FormExternalId": "0013OH",
        "FormVersion": 3,
        "DeviceId": "66313362366130366538386235666266",
        "UserExternalId": "100008",
        "StartTime": "2020-04-28T05:14:02.1500000Z",
        "CompleteTime": "2020-04-28T12:15:41.2700000Z",
        "ReceivedTime": "2020-04-28T12:15:43.1800000Z",
        "AnswerFormat": "Rich",
        "Answers": [{
                "Name": "Voorblad",
                "Type": "Group",
                "Answers": [{
                        "Name": "DSS_inspectiekaart",
                        "Type": "SelectOne"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "DSS_isolatieweerstand",
                        "Type": "SelectOne"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "spuikaart_WB1_rust",
                "Type": "Group",
                "Answers": [{
                        "Name": "hidPageTitleWB1_rust",
                        "Type": "Hidden",
                        "Value": "Spuikaart Warme bron 1 (rust)"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "WB1_spuiwatermeterGBS_rust",
                        "Type": "Text",
                        "Value": "nvt"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "WB1_spuiwatermeterTR_rust",
                        "Type": "Text",
                        "Value": "nvt"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "TaskId": "3ded50637db54034a79eaba700943f10",
        "DSRowId": "7fefda06-f24e-4611-ae64-aba700943e2b",
        "CompanyId": 55792
    },
    {
        "Id": "234hlhj0usldjlksddduf0sfdj",
        "RowId": 30,
        "FormId": "5d4a8143084b4c16a920ab0a00c905e5",
        "FormExternalId": "0013OH",
        "FormVersion": 3,
        "DeviceId": "66313362366130366538386235666266",
        "UserExternalId": "100008",
        "StartTime": "2020-04-28T05:14:02.1500000Z",
        "CompleteTime": "2020-04-28T12:15:41.2700000Z",
        "ReceivedTime": "2020-04-28T12:15:43.1800000Z",
        "AnswerFormat": "Rich",
        "Answers": [{
                "Name": "Voorblad",
                "Type": "Group",
                "Answers": [{
                        "Name": "DSS_inspectiekaart",
                        "Type": "SelectOne"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "DSS_isolatieweerstand",
                        "Type": "SelectOne"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "spuikaart_WB1_rust",
                "Type": "Group",
                "Answers": [{
                        "Name": "hidPageTitleWB1_rust",
                        "Type": "Hidden",
                        "Value": "Spuikaart Warme bron 1 (rust)"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "WB1_spuiwatermeterGBS_rust",
                        "Type": "Text",
                        "Value": "nvt"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "WB1_spuiwatermeterTR_rust",
                        "Type": "Text",
                        "Value": "nvt"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "TaskId": "3ded50637db54034a79eaba700943f10",
        "DSRowId": "7fefda06-f24e-4611-ae64-aba700943e2b",
        "CompanyId": 55792
    },
    {
        "Id": "jsidfyhw8yehrlsfuy9w0eln",
        "RowId": 30,
        "FormId": "5d4a8143084b4c16a920ab0a00c905e5",
        "FormExternalId": "0013OH",
        "FormVersion": 3,
        "DeviceId": "66313362366130366538386235666266",
        "UserExternalId": "100008",
        "StartTime": "2020-04-28T05:14:02.1500000Z",
        "CompleteTime": "2020-04-28T12:15:41.2700000Z",
        "ReceivedTime": "2020-04-28T12:15:43.1800000Z",
        "AnswerFormat": "Rich",
        "Answers": [{
                "Name": "Voorblad",
                "Type": "Group",
                "Answers": [{
                        "Name": "DSS_inspectiekaart",
                        "Type": "SelectOne"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "DSS_isolatieweerstand",
                        "Type": "SelectOne"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "spuikaart_WB1_rust",
                "Type": "Group",
                "Answers": [{
                        "Name": "hidPageTitleWB1_rust",
                        "Type": "Hidden",
                        "Value": "Spuikaart Warme bron 1 (rust)"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "WB1_spuiwatermeterGBS_rust",
                        "Type": "Text",
                        "Value": "nvt"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "WB1_spuiwatermeterTR_rust",
                        "Type": "Text",
                        "Value": "nvt"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "TaskId": "3ded50637db54034a79eaba700943f10",
        "DSRowId": "7fefda06-f24e-4611-ae64-aba700943e2b",
        "CompanyId": 55792
    }
],
"TotalRows": 3
```

}

I've deserialized the Json and listed all the entries into a gridview. When a user clicks on a row in the gridview the data of that specific object has to be loaded into another form.
The id of the entry is the unique value, so I wan't to find the object in the Json file based on the id.

```
public partial class FormulierenOverzicht : Form
{
    public FormulierenOverzicht()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormulierenOverzicht_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var json = Resource._013;
        var tmpTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new { Entries = default(DataTable) }).Entries;

        DataTable dtEntries = new DataTable();
        dtEntries = tmpTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Id", "CompleteTime");
        var dgView = dataGridView1;

        dgView.DataSource = dtEntries;
        dgView.Columns["CompleteTime"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        dgView.Columns["CompleteTime"].HeaderText = "Datum afgerond";
        dgView.Sort(dgView.Columns["CompleteTime"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
        dgView.Columns[0].Visible = false;





    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var json = Resource._013;
        string matchIdToFind = "here comes the id value";
        var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<_013.Rootobject>(json);

    }
}
```

}

I allso made a class for the Json.

How can I get the object based on the key value?

Comment: Can you post what you have  done already?

Comment: For the record, I don’t have to get the solution. A point in the right direction is enough.

Comment: So you’ve deserialised to a data table, why not jus a link query on the data table to find the desired records?

Comment: Thnx Hursey, I didn’t tought about that. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

After Googling around I've found a good solutions for my problem.

```
foreach (var entry in parsedJson.Entries.Where(entry => entry.Id.Contains(id)))
            {
                 here comes the code...
            }
```